# Extracting $! from multiple process substitutions

Tags: bash, process

Consider the following:

```
exec > >(tee -a mylog) 2> >(tee -a mylog >&2)
pspid=$!
```

Which `tee` process has the pid of `$!` above?

If we want the pid's of each `tee` processes above how do we extract them?

Comment: See also [The process substitution output is out of the order](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/403788) (you could use `rc` instead of `bash` which has `$apids` for that).

Answer (score 2):

`$!` contains the pid of the right most command in the last pipeline run asynchronously. Here, you'd just need to run `exec` twice:

```
exec > >(tee -a mylog)
out_pid=$!
exec 2> >(tee -a mylog >&2)
err_pid=$!
```

But maybe you don't need to record those pids. Those `tee` processes will exit (upon see eof) when your script (and all the processes it started and that shell its stdout/stderr) exits. And if you kill them before it does, that your script (or any process with their stdout/stderr redirected to those pipes) will get a SIGPIPE if they try to write anything on stdout/stderr.